# Very low Gflops on array elementwise product-sum opeartion with CUDA

Tags: arrays, cuda

I have two 3D arrays, being signals`S(Q,C,M)` and filters `F(Q,C,K)`. `Q` contains transforms (FFT/DHT), `C` is the channel number. Each `Q*C` is a filter. And `M` `K` are the number of signals and filters.

Now I need to perform the following operation: apply each filter for each signal, with element multiplication of 2D array `Q*C`s. There are `MK` number of `QC`s, and each pair from `S` and `F` are to be multiplied. In Matlab form it would be `Z(:,:,i,j) = S(:,:,i) .* F(:,:,j)`.

`Z` has dimension `Q*C*K*M`. It looks like a outer product on the last dimension. After that, I need to sum over all channels, resulting in a `Q*K*M` array. No need to save the intermediate result `Z`.

I have written the following CUDA kernel, but it is only showing <20 GFlops/s. Lunching parameter: `Q=1024, threadPerBlock = Q, blockPerGrid = (K, M).`

```
#define C 50
#define M 100
#define K 500

__global__ void corr5Ker(float *X, float *W, float *Z, int nChan) {

// Block index
int bk = blockIdx.x;
int bm = blockIdx.y;

// Thread index
int tx = threadIdx.x;

// Calc offsets
int xBegin = 1024 * nChan * bm;
int xStep = 1024;
int xEnd = 1024 * nChan * (bm + 1);

int wBegin = 1024 * nChan * bk;
int wStep = 1024;

float rC = 0;
// Conv
for (int ix = xBegin, iw = wBegin; ix < xEnd; ix += xStep, iw += wStep) {
    rC += X[ix + tx] * W[iw + tx];
}   
__syncthreads();

int threadId = (bk + bm * gridDim.x) * 1024 + tx;
Z[threadId] = rC;

}
```

I use `Q*C*M*K` to calculate the Flops, and the timing only contains kernel time. I also tested matrix element-wise addition and multiplication with linear kernels, if the data dimension is large enough, it can reach about 600 Gflops/s. The above operation is only slightly more complicated, but not supposed to be as low as 20 Gflops/s. At what point am I wrong?

**Edit 1**

I have corrected my code in calculating the matrix addition, and the code is only 6 Gflops/s. I tried to use saxpy, which also offered the same result. Now it is clear that what matters is the memory bandwidth.

I also corrected the above kernel with more registers, which gives around 50 Gflops/s. Now it is reasonable.

Comment: At the downvoter: The close vote (and its reason) are inappropriate. This question is feasibe (it's not a "great" question, as the description sounds a bit confusing/complicated, but should be fine for someone who is more involved). Back to the topic: My guess would be that your access pattern is simply not coalesced, but I have not analyzed this in detail.

Comment: In the first part of your post, it seems that you are performing element-wise multiplications between 2D slices of your input 3D matrices, thus filtering in the frequency domain. However, if I look at your code, the `for` loop seems to implement a convolution, so it seems that you are filtering in the time domain. Be aware that there are different possible approaches to filtering, depending on whether the kernel support is large or small. In the former case, the best would be using FFTs, or frequency domain. In the latter case, the best would be using different approaches in the time domain.

Comment: Please, note that the CUDA SDK contains several examples of implementing the convolution. In particular, you can find an example on a 2D, FFT-based convolution approach and an example of convolution in time-domain with separable kernels (using or not texture memoy). From what above said, I believe that you are improperly comparing the performance of your approach with that of an elementwise addition. Finally, I do not see any particular issue on the memory access pattern.

Comment: @JackOLantern thanks for your feedback. In fact, this problem has some engineering background and can not be fit into the SDKs. The original problem is to apply hundreds of filters to thousands of images, which is more complicated than single image with single filter. Moreover, some of the filter channels are to be averaged, which is the reason for the for loop.

Comment: @JackOLantern This problem is mixed with element wise product and matrix outer product. Thus the performance should between element operations and matrix product.That is why I compare it to matrix addition.

Comment: I haven't claimed that you can directly use one of the CUDA SDK examples, but I have said that they represent different approaches, which are possible depending on the characteristics of your problem, primarily the features of your kernel/filter. The CUDA SDK examples, and other examples throughout the literature, could give you clues on how optimizing your approach. Take a look, for example, to Chapter 5 of the "Designing Scientific Applications on GPUs" book.

Comment: I have gone through the examples and tried most of them. Shared memory is not needed in this case, adding registers and reducing threads does not help either. The memory access is already coalesced. The bottleneck might be memory throughput, so I compared it with matrix addition which also requires light ALU resource. Also, the kernel is not separable. It seems there is no better to get around this so far.

Comment: However, the operations it does is even simpler than matrix multiplication, just more complex than addition. So intuitively there should be some way to improve it.

Comment: You operation is just a bunch of vector dot products. Dot products are bandwidth limited, so to calculate your efficiency you should be calculating your GB/s bandwidth and compare that to peak, rather than Gflop/s performance.

Comment: @ngimel That is correct. I have calculated the bandwidth and it is already reaching the peak of my GPU, both Saxpy and hand written kernel; but ALU level is just 6G Flop/s. Are there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all. The performance of CUDA kernels is closely related to the ccc of the device and it's hardware, being said that:

1. Using 1024 threads per block probably you only could be able to fit a small number of blocks on an SM. This is due to the number of registers each thread needs. Shared memory its not a restriction in that case, so you are not using any.
2. Using shared memory you'll see a performance improvement.

The point 1 explain what you said:

> if the data dimension is large enough, it can reach about 600
>   Gflops/s.

Increasing the size of the data you allow the kernel to run more blocks and that means that the device is able to hide long latency operations by context switches.

My advice is (ordered by increasing complexity:

- Profile your application an see what is happening.
- Reduce the number of threads per block. That should increase the number of blocks per SM and should increase the performance you get.
- Use shared memory.

If you post a minimal functional code, I could tell you more!

Comment: Many thanks really. The task is merely doing some element wise multiplication and copy elsewhere which is quite light in ALU, very similar to matrix addition where we do not use shared memory. I tried to use less threads while increasing registers, but that is also in vein. However, I will test two similar cases with timing, one being tiled matrix multiplication with each patch doing element wise product (the task here), and the other case doing sum(A.* B, 3). Hope I can see the real bottleneck and come back to you later.

Comment: Great! Your kernel seems simple and there are no divergence between threads, but still you give so many work to each thread in those loop. If you reduce the number of threads you probably could use shared memory.